# Can we configure refresh token expiration time to unlimited in WSO2 API manager by setting -1 for RefreshTokenValidityPeriod

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We have tried to set the RefreshTokenValidityPeriod in the identity.xml as -1 to make the refresh token valid forever. But the refresh token was expired immediately when it was set to -1. We are using wso2 API manager 2.1.0 and deployed with docker.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. But, if you're fine with the security risk of having a non-expiring refresh token, you can have a non-expiring access token, instead. Both the advantage and risk are the same in 2.

Comment: @Palle please note if you regenerate a non-expiring access token (through the Store), the existing token will be revoked